# calculate distance between two computers in ad hoc network

Tags: java, networking, network-programming

I want to programme a simple programme that calculate distance between  two computers in ad hoc network . but really i dont know how to start ?? .

well my idea was to use velocity v = L/t , and after that get the Distance L (Distance )= V . t ??

Thank You

Comment: It is not that easy. You need to learn the internals of Computer Networks.

Comment: i just want to simulate thats all , its not has to be exactly distance between these computers.. so i hope of you could help me with that

Comment: What information do you have available to calculate the distance? Positioning data, signal values etc?